# Check a text is palindrome or not after ignoring punctuations

Tags: python

The code which I typed with the help of some online coding website is:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def sanitize(text):
    text = text.lower()
    forbidden =("",".",",","!","&","?")
    for c in forbidden:
        text=text.replace(c,"")
    return text

something = raw_input("enter your detail")

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = sanitize(text)
    return text == reverse(text)


if is_palindrome(something):
    print(" yes, it is palindrome")
else:
    print("no, it is not palindrome")
```

Output:

```
enter your detail:rise to vote,sir
no, it is not palindrome
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Delete superfluous information on your question please

Comment: What do you get when you print the result of `sanitize(text)`?

Comment: Please write your code in Python3. If the book you refer to is Python2, you need a new book

Comment: "rise to votesir" is not the same as "risetov ot esir". Maybe replace the spaces too?

Comment: @12944qwerty That looks like an answer to me

Comment: Side note: you don't need to write your own `reverse()` function. Python has a built-in `reversed()` function, which you can call on strings.

Comment: when spaces are removed, it works.

Answer (score 2):

"rise to votesir" is not the same as "risetov ot esir".
Maybe replace the spaces too when you sanitize?

This depends on your criteria and how you "sanitize it".

```
def sanitize(text):
    text = text.lower()
    forbidden =(" ",".",",","!","&","?") # Replaced "" with " " because it was redundant
    for c in forbidden:
        text=text.replace(c,"")
    return text
```

Comment: It is important to mention that the original `""` in OP's original `forbidden =("",".",",","!","&","?")` did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

def reverse(text):
return text[::-1]

def sanitize(text):
text = text.lower()
forbidden =(" ",".",",","!","&","?")
for c in forbidden:
text=text.replace(c,"")
return text

something = raw_input("enter your detail")

def is_palindrome(text):
text = sanitize(text)
return text == reverse(text)

if is_palindrome(something):
print(" yes, it is palindrome")
else:
print("no, it is not palindrome")